# Change Status Bar color during runtime on android in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to change the colour of the status bar during run-time programatically. I have tried this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
}
```

but it only works in the MainActivity.cs class.

I would like to change it during runtime.

Comment: DependencyService : https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service

Comment: Yes, I am currently using Dependency Injection, but I don't see how this answers my question? I cannot run it outside of the MainActivity.cs class.

Comment: `Window` is based upon the Activity's context, either store the context in a static var of your `MainActivity`, use the CurrentActivityPlugin, etc...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, could you maybe please explain what you mean?

Comment: See if my answer explains it

Answer (score 0):

#### Dependency Interface:

```
public interface IStatusBarColor
{
    void CoreMeltDown();
    void MakeMe(string color);
}
```

You need the current Activity's context which you can obtain via multiple methods; A static var on the MainActivity, using the `CurrentActivityPlugin`, etc... Lets keep it simple & hackie and use a static var, so add a static `Context` var and set it in the `OnResume`.

#### MainActivity Context

```
    public static Context context;
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        context = this;
        base.OnResume();
    }
```

#### Android Dependency Implementation:

```
public class StatusBarColor : IStatusBarColor
{
    public void MakeMe(string color)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            var c = MainActivity.context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
            c?.RunOnUiThread(() => c.Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.ParseColor(color)));
        }
    }

    public void CoreMeltDown()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                switch (i%2)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MakeMe($"#{Integer.ToHexString(Color.Red.ToArgb())}");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        MakeMe($"#{Integer.ToHexString(Color.White.ToArgb())}");
                        break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(200);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

#### Usage:

```
var statusBarColor = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarColor>();

statusBarColor?.MakeMe(Color.Blue.ToHex());

statusBarColor?.CoreMeltDown();
```