# Xamarin app doesn't receive sensor measurements in an equidistant fashion

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, xamarin.android

This question might be related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049259/xamarin-app-performance-degrading-over-time-eventually-leading-to-crash) I asked some time ago. However, the situation is now a bit different.

I'm currently developing an Android app with Xamarin that communicates via a Wi-Fi connection with some custom hardware containing a sensor. The job of my app is to retrieve the sensor data from the hardware and store it on the phone **without displaying it** (thus there is no rendering taking place). I would like to receive a continuous stream of data with equidistant temporal distances between all measurements. Unfortunately, this is not the case as the following graph, depicting the time it took to retrieve a measurement after another in milliseconds, clearly shows:
[image: Plot illustrating the temporal distances between my measurements]

My initial guess was that those peaks (ranging up to 2500 ms) correlate with the garbage collection cycles and thus decided to experiment a bit. I tried the following combinations concerning the memory heap and GC algorithms so far:

1. bridge implementation = tarjan; nursery size=256mb; soft heap limit=512mb
2. bridge implementation = old; nursery size=256mb; soft heap limit=512mb
3. bridge implementation = new; nursery size=256mb; soft heap limit=512mb

All combinations of those parameters lead to similar results. Concurrent GC is enabled. Do you have any further ideas what could cause those temporal peaks?

## Update 1

The code I'm using still looks similar to the code I used in my previous question:

```
[...]
int timeout = 1000;
while (ShootContinuously) {
    FrameCounter++;
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    var task = GetDataAndUpdateUIForContinuousShootingAsync(MyDisplayPlot, FrameCounter, StartTime, mainPage);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken)) == task) {
        // Task completed within timeout.
        // Consider that the task may have faulted or been canceled.
        // We re-await the task so that any exceptions/cancellation is rethrown.
        await task;
    } else { // timeout/cancellation logic
        Debug.WriteLine("Task is taking too long!");
        await Client.DisconnectAndStopReadTaskAsync();
        Client = null;
        GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Client = new MyClientSocket();
        await Client.ConnectAndStartReadTaskAsync();
        continue;
    }
}
await Client.DisconnectAndStopReadTaskAsync();
```

The only difference is that I don't perform any UI updates any more.

## Update 2

I sometimes see the following output:

```
> 04-10 18:17:12.501 D/Mono    ( 8751): AOT: image 'System.IO.dll.so'
> not found: dlopen failed: library not found
> 04-10 18:17:12.503 D/Mono    ( 8751): AOT: image
> '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.IO.dll.so'
> not found: dlopen failed: library not found
> 04-10 18:17:12.503 D/Mono    ( 8751): Config attempting to
> parse: 'System.IO.dll.config'. 04-10 18:17:12.503 D/Mono    ( 8751):
> Config attempting to parse:
> '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.IO/System.IO.config'.Loaded
> assembly: System.IO.dll [External]
```

Could this be related to my problem?